# set window properties (above, on all workspaces) in js/gnome-shell-extension?

Tags: mutter, javascript, gnome-shell-extension

As part of teaching myself how to make gnome-shell-extensions, I'd like to be able to tell a window to be on all workspaces on on top of all other windows.

I notice in the mutter API there is a `meta_window_set_above` in `window.c` but this doesn't seem to be exposed to the JS interface. Through a bit of trial and error I also seem to be able to call `window.set_property('above',true)` but this function appears to do nothing (there is a `'title'` property I tested on and using `set_property` on this seems to do nothing).

So, does anyone know of an alternate way to set a window's properties in a gnome shell extension? (and how to tell whether a function in the API gets exposed through javascript? I (naively) thought it'd be as easy as "oh, there's a `meta_window_set_above` in `window.c`, so I must be able to call `window.set_above(true)`, but I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question of the [gnome mailing list](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2012-April/msg00073.html) - turns out that the meta window properties are all read-only, so I can't (currently) set the above/on all workspaces options using mutter.

However, I can use a library [wnck](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/index.html) to achieve this. Whilst mutter is still preferred, this may be the only way for now.

Luckily wnck has gobject introspection, so this was sufficient:

```
const Wnck = imports.gi.Wnck;
let window = Wnck.Screen.get_default().get_active_window();
if ( window ) {
    window.make_above();
}
```

There are functions `make_above`, `unmake_above`, `pin`, `unpin`, `stick`, and `unstick` (although I don't know what the difference is between `pin` and `stick`), all listed [here](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/WnckWindow.html).